# Appium Running Safari on a Real iOS Device~ Instruments Usage Error : Specified target process is invalid: {}

Tags: ios, appium

So I am running Appium and trying to get Safari to launch on a real iOS device.
When I run my tests I am getting the following in the Appium logs.

> info: Launching instruments
>
> info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID
>   0d0404b24f2fad46051111d56d811d900cb2a762
>
> info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0d0404b24f2fad46051111d56d811d900cb2a762 {} -e UIASCRIPT
>   "/Users/trent/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-2911698fabce8e2c.js" -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra
>   without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms):
>   {"global":20000}
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 19 21:28:24 iPad2 kernel[0] :
>   flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token:
>   22
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 19 21:28:24 iPad2 lockdownd[26] :
>   Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 19 21:28:24 iPad2 kernel[0] :
>   flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token:
>   22
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 19 21:28:24 iPad2 lockdownd[26] :
>   Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 19 21:28:24 iPad2 kernel[0] :
>   flow_divert_token_set (0): Failed to get the key unit from the token:
>   22
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar 19 21:28:24 iPad2 lockdownd[26] :
>   Could not set socket option SO_OPPORTUNISTIC: Invalid argument
>
> info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Usage Error : Specified target
>   process is invalid: {}
>
> info: [debug] [INST STDERR] instruments, version 6.1 (56160) usage:
>   instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w
>   device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]
>
> info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 255 info:
>   [debug] Killall instruments info: [debug] Instruments crashed on
>   startup info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this
>   is retry #2 info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

Comment: What capabilities are you passing?

Comment: I was actually able to resolve this myself. Realized that because I was launching the browser, I did not need to have "bundleID" set.
Once i removed that everything worked as expected.

Thx for the follow-up